# ffmpeg missing a library libx265.so.79

Tags: dependencies, ffmpeg, libraries

I have upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04 and now I can't run `ffmpeg`:

```
$ ffmpeg 
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libx265.so.79: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have the lib installed but it's different version:

```
$ ls -1l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4704858 úno 23 16:57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       14 úno 23 16:57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so -> libx265.so.110
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10807296 úno 23 16:57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.110
```

I have tried to make a symlink .79 -> .110 but that ended up with an error.

Here's what it's looking for:

```
$ ldd $(which ffmpeg)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffce1f4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe866d36000)
    libvdpau.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau.so.1 (0x00007fe866b32000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fe866910000)
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007fe866708000)
    libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007fe866504000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fe8661c9000)
    libx265.so.79 => not found
    libx264.so.148 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.148 (0x00007fe865e27000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe865b1e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe865902000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe8656e4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe86531b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005587217c3000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fe865109000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fe864f05000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fe864cff000)
```

What should I do about it?

What does the .79 mean? Is that a version? According to that static build's page, the version used is `libx265: 2.4+22-c102c809fc4f`. So `.79` seems a bit off.

Comment: Where is this `ffmpeg` located? Run `which ffmpeg`. Which package, if any, owns this broken `ffmpeg`? You can probably use `dpkg -S /full/path/to/ffmpeg` to find out. Ensure you query the correct `ffmpeg` in case you have multiples installed (due to previously compiling, etc).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I had simply wherever Ubuntu installs it, no other `ffmpeg` in the system.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `type -a ffmpeg` and `apt-cache policy ffmpeg libav\* libx265\*`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have overcame the issue by downloading the static build from the link mentioned at `ffmpeg.org`. Just a note (for beginners) that you need to run it with with `./ffmpeg` rather than just `ffmpeg` while being in the directory.

Still, I would like to know how to fix the distro's package's deps.

Edit: The system's packaged `ffmpeg` works again in 17.10.